# ubuntu 12.04 usb debugging stopped working

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb, usb-debugging

using ubuntu 12.04 and LG optimus G E975, usb debugging was working fine 2 days ago and now it just stopped working, when I plug the device into my laptop (all 3 usb ports), it just shows the charging icon, here are the things I did so far:

- make sure usb debugging is enabled in developer options
- make sure the required rule is added in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules with the value:

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
- restart the adb server as root:

  sudo adb kill-server   then sudo adb start-server
- changed the usb chord
- changed the device with another device (huawei) which was also working fine 2 days ago
- lsusb doesn't show device connected

none of the above seems to work, adb devices doesn't find anything, not even ??????. it's just empty. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I've followed [This](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html) as well, and it did not work, ubuntu still can't detect the device. using **dmesg** command doesn't show any changes before or after connecting and disconnecting the device from usb port.

Comment: have you check usb debugging is enable in device settings>Developer options ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana as I mentioned as a first item in my check-list, yea it is enabled but it's still charging only, I suspect it's the laptop that is causing the problem since the other device is not working as well but sadly I don't have any other laptop or computer to check it on

Comment: try check on another usb port.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html) site. @arashmoeen

Comment: @HareshChhelana I already mentioned that in my question (all 3 usb ports)... it doesn't work

Comment: @Skynet yea man I found that after posting this question and it's already in the process of update, I'll post back the results and will ask you to post as an answer later if it worked. thanks anyway

Comment: @Skynet it did not work, I followed the link and did everything as was mentioned, still no luck and adb can't detect my device

Comment: Ok, then wait if anyone else can give some more solution about it.

Comment: Have you tried a different phone? maybe its the phone...

Comment: @Joe3112 I've tried with a huawei as I mentioned in my check-list, it used to work as well, but it's not working anymore too.

Comment: check this http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: @AlexP. I followed its instructions and still my device doesn't get connected properly, just charging.

Comment: _lsusb doesn't show device connected_ <--- That is the problem, you should be focusing on that issue first. Does connecting other USB devices show up in lsusb? Could the issue be in cable used?

Comment: @shoerat Yup for exmample it shows my mouse connected, but for the mobile device? it shows nothing. I've tested with another cable, another computer and the same result happens, they can't detect my phone as storage or anything and the usb debugging doesn't come on

Answer (score 1):

If the device is not getting detected you should probably add the vendor Id in ~/.android/adb_usb.ini with sudo permission.

In the above case add 0x1004.
After adding, restart the udev service with the command "sudo service udev restart"
Now go to your adb location and kill-server and start server with sudo permission.

Try adb devices now and adb should be able to detect your device now.

Comment: although that makes sense but it didn't help, last night I've tested 2 nexus devices on my laptop and both worked as it was supposed to but testing my own phone on another computer (which those nexus devices worked perfectly), it did not work and just started charging so I suppose it's my device... either it's usb port has got an issue or it's software fault which I'm yet to find out. but thanks anyway

Comment: It might not exactly be a usb port issue, some devices which i have used like Salora,Celkon all needed to be added like this. The same machine i tested with Nexus it automatically gets detected.Try the lsusb command and check if the particular port is available,if it shows  then I don't think it might be a port problem.

Comment: refer to my question, I've explain all the steps I took before posting the question, even dmesg doesn't show anything after connecting or disconnecting the device.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to add `OWNER="<my login>"` (e.g. `..., OWNER="port443"`) to make it work.  It is enough to re-plug device and run `adb kill-server` + `adb devices` for device to show up.  For some reason only group does not work, even though I am in that group.

I have another question on this specific issue: [Ubuntu: ADB only recognizes device if OWNER is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977034/ubuntu-adb-only-recognizes-device-if-owner-is-provided)