# Ubuntu: ADB only recognizes device if OWNER is provided

Tags: android, linux, debugging, adb, remote-debugging

The system is Ubuntu 12.04LTS

I have rules defined in /etc/dev/rules.d/51-android.rules similar to this:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1bbb", ATTR{idProduct}=="0167", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="port443"`

This all works well and ADB can see device; but, obviously, only for me.  I wanted this global rule to be applicable globally on machine for all users (or for users in "plugdev" group).

In my case if I omit OWNER, device becomes invisible to ADB.  I saw samples even omitting group (mode=0666 should make it globally available anyway, right?), but neither work in my case.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/04/universal-udev-rule-for-all-android.html

Comment: @AlexP., please read above. This is what I do, but it only works if I provide `OWNER`